# How do I compile the latest gvim from source

Tags: vim, gvim

I have found that I need to compile the lastest gvim due to [a bug I have reported](https://github.com/akitaonrails/vimfiles/issues/99), but how do I proceed?

Comment: Same on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314970/how-can-i-compile-gvim-under-ubuntu

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run the following commands in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep vim-gnome
```

to get all the build dependencies you need.
Then

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

to get the Mercurial version control system needed to download the latest Vim source code.
Then

```
hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim
```

to download the Vim source code to the subdirectory `vim` of the current directory.

```
cd vim/src
```

to change to the right directory

Now let's configure Vim for compilation (with "huge" features - see http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vimfeat.html for a description of the different feature sets)

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-features=huge
```

If `./configure` finished without any problems, then run

```
make
```

and then

```
sudo make install
```

and that should be it.

To update Vim to the latest version, just go into the `vim` directory and run

```
hg pull
hg update
```

and then re-run `configure`, `make` and `make install`.

Comment: Thanks a lot my vim is working now however gvim is still using another version how do I instruct gvim to load the same version as vim?

Comment: Unless you need the old version still, you should probably delete it using `sudo apt-get remove vim-gnome`. Otherwise you would have to ensure that `/usr/local/bin` appears before `/usr/bin` in the `$PATH` environment variable, which you should look up separately.

Comment: Anybody has an updated recipe for gvim 8.* on github?  I get 'vim' to be build, but not 'gvim'.

Comment: It might be failing to compile `gvim` if it decides to use gtk3 instead of gtk2. The latest versions of Ubuntu seem to have a vim-gtk3 package - maybe try running `sudo apt-get build-dep vim-gtk3` before compiling your own